# How to find the center of a CircleShape in Love2D?

Tags: lua, love2d

For debug purposes, I need to draw all physics bodies in my love2d game.  This is easy for polygons, but CircleShapes present a problem: I can't find their centers!

The function `getLocalCenter` seems to do exactly what I want, but it was removed in 0.8.0.  First of all, I am concerned that this removal may have been a mistake.  Second of all, I need some sort of alternative in order to draw my debug output.  Is there a function somewhere that does what I need?

Answer (score 0):

`CircleShape:getPoint` was added in Love2d `0.9.0`, which solves my problem.  As it turns out, the wiki pages I was reading off of, which I had downloaded for offline use and was using because their provided faster navigation than the online versions, were out-of-date, and did not reflect this new function.